# How to fix "My bot can't use my server emojis" discord

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

My bot can't use the emojis in my server it just writes the name of the emojis like :ZW:

I tried another emoji but it didn't work either.

```
  client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("W")) {
    message.channel.send("<a:ZW:592735656422277121>");
  }
  })
```

No error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend finding the actual emoji code by looping through all the available ones and finding the one you want rather than hardcoding its id. This will make things work even if its ID changes at some point, as long as you keep the name the same.

```
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("W")) {
        let ZW = client.emojis.find(emoji => emoji.name === "ZW");
        message.channel.send("emote: " + ZW);
    }
});
```

Make sure the casing is the same too, or use `emoji.name.toLowerCase()`.
The ZW variable is an object representing your emoji. If you want its code, you can get it with `ZW.toString()` (automatically called when concatenating it with a string).

[Documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Emoji)